# Suppress rendering of HTML link in JQuery datatable when printing

Tags: printing, datatables

Preamble: For a variety of reasons, I still have to use DataTables 1.9.

When I render a table, everything looks great, including the link that the table value leads to:

[image]

However, in the print view, the HTML link is also included:

[image]

How can I suppress the printing of the HTML link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this isn't a JQuery datatable thing — it's a bootstrap thing. The bootstrap CSS includes the following:

```
a[href]:after {
  content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}
```

If I override this in my print CSS, everything is good.

Answer (score 1):

I removed this from bootstrap css and then print is good:

a[href]:after{content:" (" attr(href) ")"}